# What is the correct way to pass the password to OpenSSL

Tags: batch-file, openssl

I am trying to setup a batch script to automate some of OpenSSL's more mundane tasks. The problem I am having, is that the typical 'passout' and 'pass' parameters still prompt for a password.

For example:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca\private\root.key.enc 4096 -pass pass:somepassword
```

and

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca\private\root.key.enc 4096 -passout pass:somepassword
```

both result in still being prompted to enter a password.  Could you please let me know what the correct parameter is. Using the stdin `<<` also will not work as I am using windows. Eventually, I will be wrapping this in C# so the parameters need to be the ones included as actual parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `-passin pass:"my password"` and `-passout pass:"my password"` which shouldn't prompt you

Comment: @Omar - Thank you, but the param was correct. I did discover the problem though.  Apparently the parameters are picky about the order they appear.  It seems that this can't be added to the end of the line.